# Google analytics tracking on main html, rest is ajax. Do active visitor status is lost without javascript refresh?

Tags: ajax, google-analytics

I have put Google Analytics tracking script into a main.html page. Main page is then never reloaded but content is updated once in a while using recurring ajax background call. I don't need to track recurring ajax calls.

```
<body>
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
...
</body>
```

Client stays there for five hours, ajax is called periodically but main page is never reloaded so an embedded ga scriptlet is not run again. Do GA statistics still count this an active session, it's dropped once tab or browser is closed?

Should I once every XX minutes call GAAPI method on a main page to refresh status on ga backend server keeping an active visitor status alive?

```
   ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I just noticed you are using the analytics.js library (and using the "ga" object), but in your second block of code, you are calling the older "_gaq" object, which can cause problems for you.

Comment: @nyuen: Good catch, I have not used _gap.push script, all I have is an initial scriptlet. I was wondering how active session works and gap.push was first hit in a google. Did not know there is two GA APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A session last for 30 minutes, by default; however, you can adjust the length of the session from 1 minute to 4 hrs.

Take a look at the Google's documentation for [How a session is defined in Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2731565?hl=en).

Comment: I made a mistake then in my html app yesterday, users were "dropped" after 30min. Should 25min periodic ga(send, pageview) call fix this?

Comment: If you're interested in prolonging your session then just adjust the session duration. Sending a call every 25 min will keep sending pageviews.